# check if polygon is self intersecting google maps v3

Tags: google-maps-api-3, polygon

i want to check if the polygon is self intersecting. After the event "polygoncomplete" is fired, this check should be done. Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Comment: See [Detecting polygon self intersection](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/80798/detecting-polygon-self-intersection)